# How to get a notification when there is a new message in an Azure Service Bus queue?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I understand that we have Azure Service Bus trigger for Azure Functions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger

I need to get a “Service Bus New Message” notification in my application that is not hosted in Azure Functions. I don’t want to limit my application hosting options to Azure Functions only.

**Questions:**

How can I get a notification when there is a new message in an Azure Service Bus queue?

What is the notification protocol/mechanism between Service Bus and Azure Function so the we have the Service Bus Trigger feature in Azure Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger uses either a `ServiceBusProcessor` or `ServiceBusReceiver` in the background, depending on the configuration.  These are responsible for polling the queue/subscription.  *([ref](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/src/Listeners/ServiceBusListener.cs#L118))*

Unfortunately, I don't know of another way to be notified for a standard namespace.   If you're using a premium Service Bus namespace, there is integration with Event Grid that can alert you when a message is available and there is no active receiver.   Details can be found in the [Azure Service Bus to Event Grid integration overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept?tabs=event-grid-event-schema).